# Передача параметров при проксировании

Tags: nginx

```
server {
       listen   80;
       server_name my_site.ru;

       access_log /home/www/my_site/logs/nginx_access.log;
       error_log /home/www/my_site/logs/nginx_error.log;

       root /home/www/my_site;
       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {
           proxy_pass       http://some_another_site.ru/with_partnerId=32423;
           proxy_set_header Host      $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Хочу понять, почему выдает ошибку 400 - по идее он же должен тот сайт показывать?

Comment: А в `proxy_pass` разве может быть указан конкретный url, а не url-префикс?
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/example.html

Answer (score 1):

ошибка появляется, скорее всего потому, что происходит не совсем то, что вы хотите: при запросе к, например, корню вашего сайта происходит пере-запрос по адресу `http://some_another_site.ru/with_partnerId=32423`.

предполагаю, что вам на самом деле требуется **добавить** к запросу **параметр** `with_partnerId=32423`.

как добавить параметр, написано, например, в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16532804/4827341). в приложении к вашему вопросу *location* будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
   location / {
       set $args with_partnerId=32423&$args;
       proxy_pass       http://some_another_site.ru;
       proxy_set_header Host      $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```